# Display sum of two db records in javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm stucked in a situation now, i need to replace grand_score with paper_score + final_score (i.e the sum of paper_score and final_score). I've tried different alternations but still no fruitful result. please help me.

```
'<td>' + result['records'][i]['paper_score'] + '</td>' + //continuous assessment
                        '<td>' + result['records'][i]['final_score'] + '</td>' + //examination
                        '<td>' + result['records'][i]['grand_score'] + '</td>' + //ca + exam
```

Comment: Judging by the lack of `$` signs with your variables and your use of `+` instead of `.` for combining strings, this appears to be javascript instead of php. Can you please confirm that?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: undefined --thats what is shows me when i use 'paper_score + final_score'

Comment: One simple question. Is result a php variable or a javascript variable.

Comment: it is a js variable

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `+` operator to add them together:

```
'<td>' + result['records'][i]['paper_score'] + '</td>' + //continuous assessment
'<td>' + result['records'][i]['final_score'] + '</td>' + //examination
'<td>' + (result['records'][i]['paper_score'] + result['records'][i]['final_score']) + '</td>' + //ca + exam
```

If `paper_score` and `final_score` are strings instead of numbers, you'll need to cast them first (assuming floats here, you could also use `parseInt()` for whole numbers):

```
'<td>' + (parseFloat(result['records'][i]['paper_score']) + parseFloat(result['records'][i]['final_score'])) + '</td>' + //ca + exam
```